How do I find the location of my Terraform state?
Is there a command to make Terraform tell me the location to which it is storing state?
I have set up a remote backend, storing Terraform state in an AWS S3 bucket. But I also see a terraform.tfstate file in my local directory, with a date modified that is after I set up the remote backend. So, I fear that Terraform might be storing state locally. I would like a way to quickly check the location of the state files Terraform is using, so that I will know if the location is local or remote.
Some commands I have tried that do not print the location of the state file:

terraform show
terraform init
terraform state list
terraform state show <resource_name>


Hi John. I'm not at my desk to try it, but terraform show -json should show the state location IRC. If the modified datetime on the local state file is newer, perhaps terraform isn't using the backend provider for some reason. When setting up terraform state in AWS I use https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-tfstate-backend which is a great way to get started.

Hm, do you know which key it is stored on? I'm not seeing it in the output, but, there's a lot.

@JohnSkilesSkinner is the local state file empty or not? Usually the backend section means it's remote. If there isn't any backend configuration, the state file is stored locally. Usually, when changing the backend from local to remote you would run the terraform init -migrate-state command. You can read more here.

Thank you, I didn't know about terraform init -migrate-state. That's helpful. Still, I'd ideally like a command that tells me, on the fly, the state file location Terraform would use if I were to run plan or apply.

You should be able to find the path in backend configuration block. Refer: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3
If for some reason you are not able to find it, you can use terraform state pull command to download the remote state file into your local. Refer:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/pull
terraform state pull > download_state_file.tfstate

This command should get the file in your local, then you can compare.

I do realize that I can look up the backend in the code, but that dosen't guarantee that it's not misconfigured somehow, or that I might accidentally be looking at the wrong file. I was hoping for a Terraform command that could double-check the state before plan or apply.

@JohnSkilesSkinner , the command mentioned above should get you the state file in question.
